# Can a large php sitemap (that uses a database connection) slow down / bog down a server?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

Yesterday I made a php sitemap for my website based on this examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4j_m4DyiPg

It uses a mysqli connection to the DB. I have about 40,000 URLs in that sitemap. I didn't notice anything bad last night, but today the site was down 3 times already. I am on a dedicated server, plenty of space and resources, but I am wondering if the new sitemap has something to do with the server being down. I contacted my hosting provider, they said they didn't have any downtime or issues. My site gives me a 500 error when it's down. I have two questions:

1. Do sitemaps get excessively crawled by spam bots which in turn can overwhelm the server?
2. Could having 40K+ URLs retrieved from a DB be considered a bad practice when it comes to sitemaps?

Like to hear your valuable input.

Comment: Yes, everything linked on the Internet gets crawled by bots both good and bad and there are a lot of them. Yes, constantly requesting the entire listing of a 40K row database table would not be good practice. How often do these URLs change? Can't you just write it to the file system once a day?

Comment: The URLs change constantly, but maybe only about 5K of them every hour / day. The rest changes every day / week / month. Maybe the best solution for me would be just requesting the latest 5K URLs? The server could probably handle that easily even if bots scan the sitemap nonstop.

Comment: Can you use a static sitemap file that gets replaced after an URL changes?  url change triggers a job, job builds new static map as new file, swaps old and new files.  That's still 5,000 db fetches a day unless you can batch up the changes (update N urls, only then do the static file update.)

Comment: I could try. I have not done it before. Will be another learning experience.

Comment: @DaveS Done and done. Used the general idea from this guy: https://chevereto.com/community/threads/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-xml-file-cron-job-chevereto.6218/ Works beautifully.